# Replacing values in columns in a dataframe in situ

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I want to replace values in certain columns in a data frame. I can do it once but it stops working once I try to build a function. I'd also like to repeat the function on a subset of all columns and I'm not sure how to do that either.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

Kid = c('Alfie', 'Brenda', 'Charlie', 'Dalma')
Likes_pie = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', NA)
Likes_sunshine = c(NA, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
Likes_friendship = c('Yes', NA, 'Yes', 'No')
my.d = cbind(Kid, Likes_pie, Likes_sunshine) %>% as_tibble()
```

I want to swop "Yes" to "T" and "No" to "F" in `Likes_pie` and `Likes_sunshine`. But I want to specify these two columns and leave out `Likes_friendship`. I want to preserve NA-s. There are no values besides "Yes" and "No".

Can do with one column:

```
my.d = my.d %>% 
  mutate(
    Likes_pie = case_when(
      Likes_pie == 'Yes' ~ 'T',
      Likes_pie == 'No' ~ 'F'
    )
  )
```

But this doesn't work in a function:

```
valConverter = function(d, var.value){
  d = d %>% 
    mutate(
      var.value = case_when(
        var.value == 'Yes' ~ 'T',
        var.value == 'No' ~ 'F'
      )
    )
return(d)
}

my.d = valConverter(my.d, Likes_sunshine)
my.d$Likes_pie
my.d$Likes_sunshine # :E
```

Assuming it did, how would I replace the column values for each column?
Is sg like `mutate_if(d, c('Likes_pie', 'Likes_sunshine'), function(x) nomConverter(x))` the way to go?

Comment: Is `Likes_friendship` one of the columns in `my.d`?

Comment: yes it is. my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `lapply` and `ifelse`. I assume `Likes_friendship` is one of the columns (Otherwise, why did you create this vector?), but whether the column is in the data frame does not affect the effectiveness of this solution.

By the way `T` and `F` are reserved word in R indicating logical value `TRUE` and `FALSE`, respectively. The character `"T"` and `"F"` may make others confused.

```
# Store the column name you want to change
cols <- c("Likes_pie", "Likes_sunshine")

my.d[cols] <- lapply(my.d[cols], function(x) ifelse(x == "Yes", "T", "F"))
my.d
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Kid     Likes_pie Likes_sunshine Likes_friendship
#   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>          <chr>           
# 1 Alfie   T         NA             Yes             
# 2 Brenda  T         T              NA              
# 3 Charlie F         T              Yes             
# 4 Dalma   NA        F              No
```

**DATA**

```
library(tidyverse)

Kid = c('Alfie', 'Brenda', 'Charlie', 'Dalma')
Likes_pie = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', NA)
Likes_sunshine = c(NA, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
Likes_friendship = c('Yes', NA, 'Yes', 'No')
my.d = cbind(Kid, Likes_pie, Likes_sunshine, Likes_friendship) %>% as_tibble()
```

Comment: If you wanted to speed it up / had a ton of data, and keep `"T"` and `"F"` as characters, you could also use `lapply(my.d[cols], function(x) c("F", "T")[(x == "Yes") + 1])` or maybe even ``lapply(lapply(my.d[cols], `==`, "Yes"), as.character)``. I know speed wasn't the goal, I just wanted to add a couple similar solutions :)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for sharing. These two are smart solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use `mutate_all`?

```
my.d %>%
    mutate_all(~case_when(
        .x == "Yes" ~ "T",
        .x == "No" ~ "F",
        TRUE ~ .x))
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Kid     Likes_pie Likes_sunshine
#  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>
#1 Alfie   T         NA
#2 Brenda  T         T
#3 Charlie F         T
#4 Dalma   NA        F
```

Or for specific columns use `mutate_at`

```
cols <- c("Likes_pie", "Likes_sunshine")
my.d %>%
    mutate_at(vars(cols), ~case_when(
        .x == "Yes" ~ "T",
        .x == "No" ~ "F",
        TRUE ~ .x))
```

giving the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mutate_at()` to do this in one hit, an `ifelse` will do what you want too:

```
(my.d <- tibble(Kid, Likes_pie, Likes_sunshine, Likes_friendship) %>%
  mutate_at(c("Likes_pie", "Likes_sunshine"), list(~ifelse(. == "Yes", T, F))))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Kid     Likes_pie Likes_sunshine Likes_friendship
  <chr>   <lgl>     <lgl>          <chr>           
1 Alfie   TRUE      NA             Yes             
2 Brenda  TRUE      TRUE           NA              
3 Charlie FALSE     TRUE           Yes             
4 Dalma   NA        FALSE          No
```

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to convert to logical column, just do `==`

```
library(dplyr)
my.d %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(cols),  list(~ . == "Yes"))
```

where

```
cols <- c("Likes_pie", "Likes_sunshine")
```